# running a python script when both bluetooth devices gets paired in raspberry PI

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have a project where I have to send data acquired from an accelerometer through a Bluetooth module connected to my pi to a smart phone. A python script will be designed to acquire and send the data to the UART of the raspberry pi. I want to run my script when the Bluetooth of my smart phone and Bluetooth module connected to the pi gets paired. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you edit the procedures it takes when the bluetooth signal is activated? I do not know too much about how bluetooth works on the pi.

Comment: its like i have a bluetooth module from robokits which is connected to the raspberry pi through the uart(txd,rxd,gnd,vcc).My smart phone bluetooth can directly pair with the bluetooth module through a key(already given in datasheet).i want my python script to run just after the bluetooths are paired and not to run always in the background.

Comment: and bluetooth works as any other normal uart connection.sending data through txd and receiving data through rxd...
thankshttp://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/a-cheap-bluetooth-serial-port-for-your-raspberry-pi this can help