# Terminal bluetooth : Must be connected to a terminal

Tags: python, bash, shell, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am actually try to run python script on my raspberry Pi from my smartphone in Bluetooth.

When I try to run this command : `python name.py`

I get always the same error : `Must be connected to a terminal`

I tried to run this command with screen but no sucess :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ screen -dm python name.py&

pi@raspberrypi:~$ screen -d -r&

Must be connected to a terminal
```

Before connexion I have always this maybe the problem is from there ? :

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Check this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=38614&p=328242 maybe you find the answer to your question here =)

Comment: And in the last comment of this question (which is the comment of the asker) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669051/running-a-python-script-when-both-bluetooth-devices-gets-paired-in-raspberry-pi I think that he found the solution but he didn't make it an answer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried this. I don't understand I can run script from gnu radio or any soft like that but when I want to run my own script, the shell reply me always the same error : Must be connected to a terminal

Comment: I'm don't really have knowledge in this field, I don't want  to mislead you  but trying to help, for that bash problem maybe you can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090974/what-does-the-shcannot-set-terminal-process-group-1-inappropriate-ioctl-for . Try to ask a new question about that bash error first, so you proceed you problem "piece" by "piece" .

Comment: Thanks for yor help. I found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471261/must-be-connected-to-a-terminal-error-with-screen-x-command-on-a-linux-contai